# Artefacts showing up in Cycles Render

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, artifacts

Decided to try some digital sculpting tools and learn some UV mapping with some success. However, now my render result shows up some weird artefacts. These things appear in viewport previews as well. Anybody know how to get rid of these and what is their origin? As you can see in the closeup image, there is some kind of pattern that is showing up from beneath the texture map. This pattern shows up in a Cycles render as well. The image is meant to look like a clean, crisp basic render without any patterns showing up on the 3d model.

[image]

[image]

Comment: We don't know what your image is *meant* to look like, so identifying what are artefacts and what aren't is difficult. Please use the [edit] link below your question to add more details as to what isn't looking like what you expect.

Comment: For some reason the image you posted didn't look like a 3d model. It seems more like a picture plane with a hand sketch imported on screen. Hmmm...

Comment: Added a second image that shows the kind of artefacts I'm talking about. The image is meant to look like a clean, crisp basic render without any patterns showing up on the 3d model.

Comment: Try opening Object data tab in Properties edtior, Geometry Data rollout and press Clear Custom Split Normals data button. This looks like custom normals on the mesh.

Comment: Wonderful, that removed the pattern. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @JanneJ.Vesala your edit was good. We now know what the problem is, however we still do know know anything about your material. Please add a screen shot of the node tree.